# Which Loop function would better suit to read the cells and get the total?

Tags: vba, loops

I have a table with a few cells in blank and the other ones filled in. The ones filled I read as value 12 which I'll later sum up for each row and add to the last column as Total.

At first, I thought on doing a function to read the cells filled in as value = 12 and add to a counter, then create a sub to put the total on the last column. This is the idea of function I had in mind.

```
Public Function TestValue(ByRef rRng as Range) As Long

    Dim rCell as Range
    Dim lCont as Long

    For Each rCell in rRng.Cells
        If isEmpty(rCell.Value) = False then
            lCont = lCont + 12
        Else
        End If
    Next rCell
    TestValue = lCont

End Function
```

I came up with a Do While just so you can have an idea on what I'm trying to do.

```
Public Sub Test()

Do

ActiveSheet.Range("I2:I8").Value = TestValue

Loop While isEmpty(Range("I2:I8")) = False

End Sub
```

Comment: What exactly is the question/problem?  By the way, IsEmpty(Range("I2:I8")) won't work here - it will always return False.

Comment: It's basically a roster, where the table shows days of the week on column header plus a last one for total hours and the employees names on the row header. The cells are filled with the shift period (7:00 - 19:00 or 19:00-7:00), but I need to read as 12 because the total hours can't surpass 48h/week.

Answer (score 0):

For Each is the less human-error prone loop. I find it's easy to accidentally write an infinite loop in the Do While format For example norie mention's in the comments that this example should get stuck in an infinite loop: *IsEmpty(Range("I2:I8")) won't work here - it will always return False*

Answer (score 0):

Does it need to be VBA? You could do this with a simple formula.

```
=COUNTA(I2:I8)*12
```

Comment: I thought of VBA, because I wanted to leave a "check" button, so the code would warn me if any of the following rules were being broken:
1.Work for more than 4 days straight
2.Have more than 48h assigned per week

I managed the 4 days straight, but I can't get through the 48h/week